# Strongly Connected Component in Directed Graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph

Why do we need to transpose the graph for getting SCCs (strongly connected components) of it? I know it gives the correct answer but I am not getting the logic.Please can someone help me with that.

Comment: Short answer: We don't.

Comment: You probably mean a directed graph, not a directed **acyclic** graph. I suppose this is about [Kosaraju's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directed Acyclic Graphs do not contain any nontrivial strongly connected components, because a strongly connected component by definition contains a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I have written in simple English. Hope [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-we-are-transposing-or-reversing-the-directions-of-all-arcs-edges-in-the-Kosaraju-two-pass-algorithm/answer/Prakash-Deivakani) will help.